# how to Display IPv4 Address Not IPv6

Tags: c#, ip, show

I am having this problem, I wrote a small app to display the computers hostname and IP address.

Hostname horks no problem, the issue I am sitting with is...

On some Windows 7 / 8 computers is displays the IPv6 Frown | :(

How do I force to only return IPv4 everytime?

**This is my Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace IPChecker
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     label1.Text = "Host Computer: " + Dns.GetHostName();
     foreach (IPAddress address in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
     {
       label2.Text = "IP Address: " + address;
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being off topic, but is that user name really allowed?!

Comment: I kind of feel that as a black guy I can use it? or how ?

Comment: other black people might still be offended as the word is derogatory in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with an empty hostname ?

Following MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> When an empty string is passed as the host name, this method returns the IPv4 addresses of the local host for all operating systems except Windows Server 2003; for Windows Server 2003, both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the local host are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Declare a String..

```
public static string Ipv4() 
    {
        string ipv4Address = String.Empty;

        foreach (IPAddress currentIPAddress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
        {
            if (currentIPAddress.AddressFamily.ToString() == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork.ToString())
            {
                ipv4Address = currentIPAddress.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return ipv4Address;
    }
```

Comment: Just one small thing.. While I am joined to my VPN it returns my VPN IPv4 and not from the LAN? What do you think? Can I get around this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Busy having a holiday.So you are connected to a VPN..FYI Many corporate enterprise VPN concentrators/endpoints work like Cisco's. In the Cisco world, by default. In your case your local LAN connection is turned off by default. Try [This Link](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-67204-vpn-connects-but-no-remote-lan-access).